# How Am I able to split a text file into two different arrays?

Tags: java, text, readfile

I have this method which reads the file and converts it into an array. The text file looks something like this, but there can be any number of items on the text file:

Ball    200
Car     20000
Goat        200

etc.

I need to split each line with a \n delimiter and each word from the number with a \t delimiter, but I'm not sure the syntax to use to actually split it that way and add each one to a different array (i.e. ball goes into one array and 200 goes into another). I figured I could split each line inside of the method I have, but I was not sure how to implement it.

EDIT: This is for a class and I'm not actually allowed to use any other storage system in the program besides arrays. :')

```
public static String[] readFile(String fileName) {
    try {
        
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        //Gets the length of the text file. How many lines there are.
        int wordCount = 0;
        while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            fileScanner.nextLine();
            wordCount++;
        }
        if(wordCount <= 0) 
            return null;
        
        //Creates an array using the length from the previous code.
        String[] finArr = new String[wordCount];
        fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        for(int i = 0; i <  finArr.length; i++) {
            if(!fileScanner.hasNextLine())
                break;
            finArr[i] = fileScanner.nextLine();
        }
        return finArr;
            
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: try to split each line using `split("\t")`.

Comment: It's also not useful to read the full file just to get the number of lines. Just read each line and store the results to 2 `ArrayList`s

Comment: `try (Stream<String> s = java.nio.file.Files.lines(java.nio.file.Path.of(fileName))) { return s.toArray(String[]::new); }`.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Problem is, I'm not allowed to use array lists as this is part of a class and that was one of the requirements. I've figured out how to split it at the tab, but when I do, I'm not sure how to add each of the parts of the line (the name, and then the number) to different arrays. No idea how to access the different parts of that line.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "Ball 200\nCar 20000\nGoat 200";
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(data))) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            String[] tokens = line.split("\\s");
            words.add(tokens[0]);
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]));
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(words);
    System.out.println(numbers);
    //If you really need it as an array
    String[] arrWords = words.toArray(new String[]{});
    Integer[] arrNums = numbers.toArray(new Integer[]{});

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrWords));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrNums));
}
```